# How do i do case when with string not equal to... Then blank?

Tags: sql

I have a list of product and would like to create a syntax as:

```
case when product is not 'apple' or product is not 'pear' or product is not 'plum' then 0 else product end
```

How do i do this?
I tried

```
case when product <> 'apple' 
     when product <> 'pear' 
     when product <> 'plum' then 0 
     else product 
end
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN Product NOT IN ('Apple', 'Pear', 'Plum') THEN 0
            ELSE Product
        END 
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the fields in your table, but it would look something like this

```
SELECT case when (Product <> 'apple' 
                  OR Product <> 'pear' 
                  OR Product <> 'plum'
                  ) then 0 else Product end as ProductName
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it just like you asked, using "OR" to separate the conditions instead of "WHEN".

Comment: Got it! thanks all! But I have another question. So we have variety of products, including fruits and non-expired stuff such as paper.
Product  --------- Expiration 
How can I do case statement to show: case when product is not apple or product is not orange then fill the expiration 1?

Comment: @user3508386 You should update your question or create another one since you have now a new requirement. Also, choose the answer that better fits your need and mark it as the one.